# I would like to get different events for hardware (bar-code scanner) key press events and virtual keyboard press events in Xamarin UWP application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I would like to get different events for hardware (bar-code scanner) key press events and virtual keyboard press events in Xamarin UWP application.

I have just tried the Windows.BarcodeScanner API's but the bar-code scanner that we use doesn't support SPP mode. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner

And I have created an custom control to listen to Keypress events, but I'm getting both virtual keyboard key press event and Hardware KeyPress Event, since the barcode scanners works in HID mode, all bar-code scanners are considered as Key Boards.

Comment: This is actually not a programming question, its just a statement of intent. Have you tried anything? what have you researched? what isn't working for you. Unfortunately this is way too broad in its current format

Comment: I have already tried Barcode Scanner API's.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.barcodescanner

Comment: And I have created an custom control to listen to Keypress events, but I'm getting both virtual keyboard key press event and Hardware KeyPress Event, since the barcode scanners works in HID mode, all bar-code scanners are considered as Key Boards.

Comment: Add that comment to your question, it makes the question better